# LINQ generates unexpected SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq, .net-core

I'm new in .NET Core and probably don't understand nature of LINQ well.

Trying to filter Oracle table using LINQ

```
var rows = TableLoan.Where(x => x.OfficeId == 10
                                && x.IssueDate >= IssueDateFrom
                                && x.IssueDate <= IssueDateTo
                                && x.DueDate >= DueDateFrom
                                && x.DueDate <= DueDateTo);
rows = rows.Skip(PerPage * (Page-1)).Take(PerPage);
result = rows.ToList();
```

When I check the SQL in the database, it looks a bit strange for me and logic is different

```
SELECT
       "x"."DUE_DATE",
       "x"."ISSUE_DATE",
       "x"."OFFICE_ID"
FROM "LOAN" "x"
WHERE (((("x"."OFFICE_ID" = 10) AND ("x"."ISSUE_DATE" >= :issueDateFrom_0)) AND
        ("x"."ISSUE_DATE" <= :issueDateTo_1)) AND ("x"."DUE_DATE" >= :dueDateFrom_2))
  AND ("x"."DUE_DATE" <= :dueDateTo_3)
OFFSET :p_4 ROWS FETCH NEXT :p_5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Expected WHERE section

```
SELECT
       "x"."DUE_DATE",
       "x"."ISSUE_DATE",
       "x"."OFFICE_ID"
FROM "LOAN" "x"
WHERE "x"."OFFICE_ID" = 10 
  AND "x"."ISSUE_DATE" >= :issueDateFrom_0
  AND "x"."ISSUE_DATE" <= :issueDateTo_1 
  AND "x"."DUE_DATE" >= :dueDateFrom_2
  AND "x"."DUE_DATE" <= :dueDateTo_3
OFFSET :p_4 ROWS FETCH NEXT :p_5 ROWS ONLY;
```

How should I change LINQ to stop generate useless parentheses?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will always put parentheses around binary expressions such as &&. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23895. Is there a functional issue you are concerned about?

Comment: Well, yes. parentheses change the logic of SQL, changes plan and execution path. And in fact, it comes to different results

Comment: How is the logic different - am I missing something?  When your write code generation, you want to write code that works every time.  Adding additional parentheses helps prevent weird side effects with virtually no cost.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about results. I was worry about sql plan since I`m not managing how SQL looks like and EF decides somehow what will be the final SQL.

Comment: @ChrisYungmann, thank for the github link. It explains the reason

Comment: Just saying: as you use `>=` and `<=` (so that both boundaries are included), you could have used `between` instead. Try and see what happens.

Comment: @EveinDev, when you disappoint LINQ, do not just move to the Dapper, but also try `linq2db`. This query do not have bad execution plan, but later you will find that EF is not so good in SQL generation.